# Reading xml files after unzipping using rubyzip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, rubyzip

```
 require 'active_support/core_ext'
 require 'open-uri'
 require 'zip/zip'


 zipfilename = open(url which returns a zip file with no of xml files inside)
 Zip::ZipFile.open(zipfilename) do |zipfile|
   zipfile.each do |entry|  
    xml = File.open(entry).read
    xml_to_hash = Hash.from_xml(xml)
   end
end
```

when i print try to print variable entry, it comes out as file_name.xml . Error comes from 
xml = File.open(entry).read.

Error:

```
test.rb:51:in `initialize': can't convert Zip::ZipEntry into String (TypeError)
from test.rb:51:in `open'
from test.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `entry` you are iterating over is not a real file. it just represents a file in your archive. i think that you need to transform your entry wich is of type `Zip::ZipEntry` into something that can be read.

see the example at http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html

as far as i have seen you can get an io like object by calling `get_input_stream` or just call read: http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipEntry.html#M000135

Comment: Thanx . i used get_input_stream to get the data.

Answer (score 4):

instead of

```
xml = File.open(entry).read
```

try

```
xml = zipfile.read(entry)
```